# Adding multiple lists to a dictionary in Python ends up overwriting previous list items?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm relatively new to software and Python and I have been working on this issue for a few hours now. I also tried googling but was unable to find an answer to my problem.

I have a dictionary with 3 lists in it. these list contain two values. I'm trying to fill a second dictionary with lists with the results of adding the values in the list from the first dictionary to a calculated position of a certain item.

So for instance the first list of the first dictionary contains the values 21 and 25. My first calculated position is 100. Now I want my second dictionary to have a list with the values 121 and 125. The second list item contains the values -21 and -25. This should result in a second list for the second dictionary with the values 79 and 75. The idea is that the second dictionary will contain n positions x 3 lists = 3n list items.

I have created 3 for loops nested together with a temporary list item. I calculate the values, add the to the temp list and if I'm finished with the first list I add them to the second dictionary.

When I look at the results of the `print("adding" ,str(tempList), "with key", str(key))` I see that the code does what I'm expecting. But looking at the result of `print(forbiddenAreas)` I see something else. It looks like the last list is being placed on al keys.

```
pitch = 100
numberItems = 3

forbiddenAreaItem = {
    "area1": [21, 25],
    "area2": [-21, -25],
    "area3": [12, 15]
}

forbiddenAreas = {}
tempList = []

if numberItems == 1:
    # print("There is one item")
    firstItemDistance = 0
else:
    # print("There are multiple items")
    firstItemDistance = ((numberItems / 2) - 0.5) * pitch

key = 1

for i in range(numberItems):
    itemLocation = firstItemDistance - pitch * i
    for y in forbiddenAreaItem:
        tempList.clear()
        for x in forbiddenAreaItem[y]:
            tempList.append(itemLocation + x)
        forbiddenAreas[key] = tempList
        print("adding" ,str(tempList), "with key", str(key))
        key += 1
print(forbiddenAreas)
```

I tried switching around the `forbiddenAreas[key] = tempList` in the other loops but was unable to generate a working solution. I also tried using `forbiddenAreas.update` instead of the current method.

Comment: Apparently you're sharing `tempList` with every change you make. Just create a new instance.

Comment: you keep adding *the same list* to your dictionary: `forbiddenAreas[key] = tempList`. Every key in `forbiddenAreas` refers to the *same list*